# Create a table with maximum values out of 2 combined tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently running into a problem with SQL Server (SSMS 17.4), I have combined 2 tables with different columns into 1 table, making use of the unique ID done in `Abc_ID`.

Table 1

```
Abc_ID  Color   Value
-----------------------
1               1
2   a          -0.5
2   b           0
2   c          -0.1
2   d           0
2   e           0
2   f           0
2   g           1
2   h           3
2   i          -5
3   a          -0.9
4   a          -.023
5   a          0
5   b          7.548
5   c          -0.8774
6   a          1
6   b          0.5
6   c          0
7   a          2.1
7   b          -1
7   c          -2.5
8   a          -1.1
8   b           5
```

Table 2

```
Abc_ID  ProductLine Name
----------------------------
1       prod1   INTERCEPT
2       prod1   BASE
3       prod1   RawCost
4       prod1   FEAT1
5       prod1   FEAT2
6       prod1   FEAT3
7       prod1   FEAT4
8       prod1   FEAT5
```

Table 1 just returns the material (`Abc_ID`), the color and the value, and table 2 returns the productline and the name per material.

The merged table now looks like

```
Abc_ID,Color, Value, Productline, name
```

Query:

```
select 
    ah.Abc_ID, ah.Color, ah.value, ad.ProductLine, ad.name
From 
    [dbo].[table1] ah 
Join 
    [dbo].[tl_table2] ad on ah.Abc_ID = ad.Abc_ID
```

Now, I would like to calculate the MAX value of the color (as a material can have different colors, only 1 color per material is the most expensive)

```
where 
    (ah.Abc_ID, ah.value) in (select ah.Abc_ID, max(ah.value)
                              from [dbo].[table1] 
                              group by [dbo].[table1].Abc_ID)
```

But that code throws an error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

What am I doing wrong here?

Expected result should be 1 max value per `Abc_ID`

```
Abc_ID  Color   Value   ProductLine Name
------------------------------------------
1               1       prod1   INTERCEPT
2          h    3       prod1   BASE
3          a    -0.9    prod1   RawCost
4          a    -0.023  prod1   FEAT1
5          b    7.584   prod1   FEAT2
6          a    1       prod1   FEAT3
7          a    2.1     prod1   FEAT4
8          b    5       prod1   FEAT5
```

Comment: JOIN with the sub-query instead.

Comment: Questions like this always get faster and better answers if you include sample data and expected outcome in your question

Comment: sql server does not supports this syntax `where (col1, col2) in ...`

Comment: can you post your sample data as text not as an image. For us to help you we sometimes need to create a temp table and fill it with your sample data. And when you post it as an image we have to type in every value in stead of copy past

Comment: Added tables to it. Unfortunately, the code shows up as a snippet. Hope it is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server does not supports this syntax `where (ah.Abc_ID, ah.value) in`

From your sample data and expected outcome this might do it for you

```
declare @table1 table (Abc_ID int, Color varchar(1), Value decimal(16,2))
declare @table2 table (Abc_ID int, ProductLine varchar(10), Name varchar(10))

insert into @table1 (Abc_ID, Color, Value)
values (1, null, 1), (2, 'a', -0.5), (2, 'b', 0), (2, 'c', -0.1), (2, 'd', 0), (2, 'e', 0), (2, 'f', 0), (2, 'g', 1), (2, 'h', 3),
(2, 'i', -5), (3, 'a', -0.9), (4, 'a', -0.023), (5, 'a', 0), (5, 'b', 7.548), (5, 'c', -0.8774), (6, 'a', 1), (6, 'b', 0.5),
(6, 'c', 0), (7, 'a', 2.1), (7, 'b', -1), (7, 'c', -2.5), (8, 'a', -1.1), (8, 'b', 5)

insert into @table2 (Abc_ID, ProductLine, Name)
values (1, 'prod1', 'INTERCEPT'), (2, 'prod1', 'BASE'), (3, 'prod1', 'RawCost'), (4, 'prod1', 'FEAT1'),
(5, 'prod1', 'FEAT2'), (6, 'prod1', 'FEAT3'), (7, 'prod1', 'FEAT4'), (8, 'prod1', 'FEAT5 ')

select ah.Abc_ID,
       (select top 1 ah2.Color from @table1 ah2 where ah2.Abc_ID = ah.Abc_ID order by ah2.Value desc) as Color, 
       max(Value) as Value,
       ad.ProductLine,
       ad.Name
from   @table1 ah
  left join @table2 ad on ah.Abc_ID = ad.Abc_ID  
group by ah.Abc_ID, ad.ProductLine, ad.Name
```

This produces this result :

```
Abc_ID  Color   Value   ProductLine Name    
------  -----   -----   ----------- ----    
1       null    1       prod1        INTERCEPT  
2       h       3       prod1        BASE   
3       a      -0,9     prod1        RawCost    
4       a      -0,023   prod1        FEAT1  
5       b       7,548   prod1        FEAT2  
6       a       1       prod1        FEAT3  
7       a       2,1     prod1        FEAT4  
8       b       5       prod1        FEAT5
```

You can also test it yourself and fiddle with this here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a90f0/1

Comment: Added sample data and expected result to the formula + made some spelling changes

Comment: is all the information provided good enough or would you like to have more?

Comment: @Thijsk Yes I think so, I have changed my answer. Check it out if this meets your need

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support multiple columns in an `IN` filter. You should use `EXISTS` instead.

Change

```
where 
    (ah.Abc_ID, ah.value) in (select ah.Abc_ID, max(ah.value)
                              from [dbo].[table1] 
                              group by [dbo].[table1].Abc_ID)
```

for

```
where 
    EXISTS (
        select 
            'there is a match'
        from 
            [dbo].[table1] AS T
        group by 
            T.Abc_ID
        HAVING
            T.Abc_ID = ah.Abc_ID AND
            max(T.value) = ah.value)
```